# How to configure a specific service operation to be accessible through a different End Point

Tags: wcf

I have single service contract that has 2 service operations. Let me call these operations as X1 and X2. How do I configure X1 to be accessible through HTTP and X2 to be accessible through TCP/IP.

If I configure the service contract to be accessibel to TCP/IP end point then both X1 and X2 will be accessible through TCP/IP. Same is the case if I configure the same service contract with HTTP protocol.

I could have two different service contracts for achieving what I want, but I want to know if I could achieve the same through a single service contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the entire service contract has the same binding applied and you cannot alter access on a per operation method. Instead you should just create two different service contracts and expose them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish one service contract to more than one binding, although this does expose both operations in both endpoints.